# ajax + ASP MVC Ambigous Controllers

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I work on project which contains 2 controllers with same name in different namespaces

```
Web.Mvc.Areas.Company.Controllers
{
    public class TestController {}
}

Web.Mvc.Areas.Employment.Controllers
{
    public class TestController {}
}
```

I need to send the file by ajax to TestController in Employment namespace

```
 $.ajax({
                                url: 'Test/UploadFiles',
                                type: "POST",
                                contentType: false,
                                processData: false,
                                data: fileData,
                                success: function(result) {
                                    alert(result);
                                },
                                error: function(err) {
                                    alert(err.statusText);
                                }
                            });
```

I'm getting error 500 after request, app found two controllers with the same name. Is there any possibility to put the correct namespace into ajax request?

Comment: If it is under an area, Are you not supposed to include the area name in the url (as per the default area route registration) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Employment/Test/UploadFiles',
            type: "POST",
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: fileData,
            success: function(result) {
                alert(result);
            },
            error: function(err) {
                alert(err.statusText);
            }
        });
```

or event better if you can inject Razor syntax:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("UploadFiles", "Test", new {area = "Employment"})',
            type: "POST",
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: fileData,
            success: function(result) {
                alert(result);
            },
            error: function(err) {
                alert(err.statusText);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Best "type-safe" way (when coupled with refactoring etc. - I use it loosely, as it doesn't produce compiler errors; just helps with refactoring tools) is definitely the `'@Url.Action()'` method. Also, note the enclosing `'` marks, as this will need to be rendered as a string in the JS

Answer (score 0):

You could use [attribute based routing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/)